# BOOTSTRAP Why not data toggle run çanta link?

Tags: bootstrap-4

why not run code ? dropdown ? `

```
    <ul class="nav border-bottom ">

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">çanta</a>

            <div class="dropdown-menu">

                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">PC</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">PC</a>
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">PC</a>


            </div>



        </li>


    </ul>
```

why not run code ? dropdown ? çanta link ` çanta link why not run code ? dropdown ? çanta link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure that you paste the code that is required for bootstrap to work with javascript between the body tags.  I mentioned it as a comment between codes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <ul class="nav border-bottom ">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">çanta</a>
      <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">PC</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">PC</a>
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-item">PC</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

<!-- These labels are supposed to be here. -->

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```